# How to limit catch all urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django project with specific urls, setup by a 'catchall' URL.

This is so I can go to `mysite/living`, and have it pass living as a parameter and pull up the appropriate details from my db.

My urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url('about/', views.about_view, name='about_view'),
url('contact/', views.contact_view, name='contact_view'),
url('(?P<colcat>[\w\-]+)/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
url('(?P<colcat>[\w\-]+)/$', views.collection_view, name='collection_view'),
```

I am running into the problem where, anything can be passed as a parameter. This is particularly notable with search engines, where `mysite/index.html/index.html` returns a valid page.

Is there a way to limit the urls that are 'allowed' to be matched?

Comment: stop writing catch ALL urls?

Comment: Are you worried about `mysite/index.html/index.html` being indexed by search engines? Then you should probably define your `sitemaps.py` with valid urls.

Comment: @bryan60 not really a useful response. Having the url setup the way I have is letting me use one page and one view to show numerous different pages, which seems more efficient, that duplicating the same view and pages numerous times just to change one word.

Comment: @spiritsree I'd like to stop anyone from being able to pass any parameter via a url and have it result in a 'valid' page. How will defining valid urls in sitemaps.py solve this issue? If that's the solution it seems like it might be a good answer to this question.

Comment: You're writing a CATCH ALL. write a url regex that captures what you actually want to capture and not ALL. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: also there's no reason you can't have multiple defined URLs pointed at the same view / page....

Comment: @bryan60 so how would you specify specific urls where part of the url can be passed to the view, in my case `colcat` in the sample I gave above?

Comment: the part between the brackets is a regex. You can write a regex of basically any complexity.

Comment: @bryan, that's missing the point. There is no regexp I can write that will capture all the terms I need to capture whilst not also capturing stuff I don't want to allow. THAT is the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Can't say for sure without knowing exactly what you're trying to capture. The POINT is exactly that you've written an overly broad regex and you need to narrow it. You can definitely get more narrow than what you've wrriten which translates to "match absolutely anything including non valid url characters"

Comment: Even I make it more narrow it will still capture things I don't want to allow. Words I want to capture would be things like 'bedroom', 'living', ;'dining'. That's why my question was not on narrowing the regexp, but on whitelisting allowed urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely for a user to enter/modify URLs manually while browsing. Everyone just googles and clicks whatever link is shown by the search engine. So, You just need to restrict what the search engine indexes.

This can be done by adding a `sitemap.xml` file to the root of your website.

`sitemap.xml` specifies all the urls of your website along with some additional information inorder to make it easier for search engines to crawl. If you don't add a `sitemap.xml`, search engines try to crawl through every possible url. **If added they wont.**

There is already a sitemap generating framework provided by django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Comment: Thanks spiritsree, this seems like the best solution. I can still look at locking down regex in the future.